# Getting a Count of Array Items that Meet a Certain Criteria ini php

Tags: php, arrays, count

How to count an array within an conditional:

```
$array = array(
    '2018/11/24',
    '2018/11/25',
    '2018/12/1',
    '2018/12/2',
    '2018/12/3'
); //specified date

$start = strtotime('2018/11/23');

$then = strtotime('2018/11/26');
```

how to count the array that meet the

```
criteria >= $start and <=$then
```

Comment: You can use array_filter to filter the data according the condition and count.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, consider making the [tour] and also have a look into [ask]

Comment: function my_function($item_values)
  {
   $start=('2018/11/25');
   $then=date('Y/m/d');
  if ($item_values>=$start&&$item_values<=$then)
  {
  return true;
  }
  return false;
  }
  $item_list=array('2018/11/17','2018/11/18','2018/11/24','2018/11/25','2018/12/1','2018/12/2','2018/12/8','2018/12/9','2018/12/15','2018/12/16','2018/12/22','2018/12/23','2018/12/25','2018/12/29','2018/12/30');
  
  echo count(array_filter($item_list,"my_function"));

//today is 2018-12-6, the result should be "3", but why it return to "1"?

if $start changed to "2018-11-24" the result is "2"

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach loop as first attempt :

```
$array = array(
    '2018/11/24',
    '2018/11/25',
    '2018/12/1',
    '2018/12/2',
    '2018/12/3'
);

$start = strtotime('2018/11/23');
$then = strtotime('2018/11/26');

foreach ($array as $date)
    strtotime($date) >= $start && strtotime($date) <= $then and $count++;

echo "$count elements matches criteria";
```